# How to move subfolders organized in Google Drive filed together in wrong folder?

Tags: google-drive

How to move multiple subfolders that are organized in Google Drive under a coherent overall project heading that were accidentally all moved together into an unrelated file? Need to pull out this large file with all its subfiles in place out of the other file where it doesn't belong. Needs to stand on its own!

Answer (score 1):

- press and hold down **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** key
- select folders you want to move
- right-click on the selection
- select **Move to**
- click on the back arrow
- select where you want to drop those selected folders / or create a new folder and drop it there

[image: 0]
[image: 0]